# How do I update a [Schema.Types.Mixed]?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, mongoose-schema

I am using Schema.Types.Mixed  to store "profiles" and here's my Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    profiles:{
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed
    }
}
```

Suppose I have a document with values:

```
{
    name: "XYZ"
    profiles:{
       "fb" : {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "pic": "source",
            "link": "www.fb.com/xyz"
        },
       "twitter" : {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "pic": "source",
            "link": "www.twitter.com/xyz"
        }  
    }
}
```

I want to add another field "youtube". How do I write updateOne query such that it upserts this new field in profiles? And how do I update values of these inner fields? Suppose I want to update only "link" fields of fb, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation pipeline of Mongo

> How do I write updateOne query such that it upserts this new field in
> profiles?

```
db.profiles.aggregate( [
        {
           $addFields: {
              "profiles.youtube": "add the data here"
           }
        }
   ] )
```

> And how do I update values of these inner fields?

```
db.profiles.aggregate( [
        {
           $addFields: {
              "profiles.twitter.name": "add the data here"
           }
        }
   ] )
```

This will update the existing field. This pipeline works well if you want to make changes to the whole collection. For more details check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#:%7E:text=To%20add%20field%20or%20fields,See%20example.).

If you want to do that for one document you can do this:

```
db.profiles.update({"name": "XYZ" },{$set : {"profiles.youtube":"add data here"}});

// to update existing data
db.profiles.update({"name": "XYZ" },{$set : {"profiles.twitter":"add data here"}});
```